# Disabling Comments - Video's ResponseURI is System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Because Youtube Data Api v3 does not allow disabling comments for videos yet...  Im trying to use Youtube Data API v2 to retrieve a video, update its settings to disable comments and upload it back.

I was able to do this a few days ago, and I am not sure why things are not working now.  One thing that I am running into is when I retrieve a video, I can update the settings and when I upload it back I get a null reference exception.  Strange.

Looks like the video's responseURI is returning as a system.SystemNullReference Exception.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
    private void DisableComments(string videoId)
    {

        Google.YouTube.Video ourVideoToUpdate = SetAcessControl( channelId, videoId, "comment", "denied");
        UpdateVideoSettings( ourVideoToUpdate);

    }

    private Google.YouTube.Video SetAcessControl(string channelId, string videoId, string type, string permission)
    {

        Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + channelId + "/uploads/" + videoId);

        Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoGenerator", DeveloperKeyHere, UsernameHere, PasswordHere);

        Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest ourRequest = new Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest(settings);

        Google.YouTube.Video videoToAdjust = new Google.YouTube.Video();
        try
        {


             Google.YouTube.Video video = ourRequest.Retrieve<Google.YouTube.Video>(videoEntryUrl);


            var exts = videoToAdjust.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements
                      .Where(x => x is Google.GData.Extensions.XmlExtension)
                      .Select(x => x as Google.GData.Extensions.XmlExtension)
                      .Where(x => x.Node.Attributes != null && x.Node.Attributes["action"] != null && x.Node.Attributes["action"].InnerText == type);


            var ext = exts.FirstOrDefault();

            if (ext != null) ext.Node.Attributes["permission"].InnerText = permission;
         }
         catch (Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException ex)
        {
            videoToAdjust = null;
        }

        return videoToAdjust;

    }

    private void UpdateVideoSettings(Google.YouTube.Video videoToUpdate)
    {
        Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoGenerator", DeveloperKeyHere, UsernameHere, passwordHere);
        Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest ourUpdateRequest = new Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest(settings);

        try
        {
            // NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION HERE - cant upload
            ourUpdateRequest.Update<Google.YouTube.Video>(videoToUpdate);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


    }
```

Any help in understanding how to update this video would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently video responses have been disabled as of March 4, this was working a few weeks ago, but the deprication must have disabled the ResponseURI.

Anyone know how to disable video comments in v3 youtube api?

Comment: You can use [channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update) resources update method which lets you to use brandingSettings.channel.moderateComments.

Comment: Thanks hipokito - but I think this only allows the moderation of comments, NOT the disabling of comments.  I need to be able to not allow comments at all

Comment: Property description states:
This setting determines whether user-submitted comments left on the channel page need to be approved by the channel owner to be publicly visible. The default value is false.
If that is not disabling comments, then what is? You mean like, remove the input field? If so, I believe it is impossible.

Comment: [Issue 473](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=473) asks for the capability to disable comments to be added to API V3. Click the star to indicate you agree with the request and to get updated on status.

Comment: I tried setting the brandingSettings.channel.moderateComments property but get "Access Violation". The program 'XXX.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Google developers have migrated the issue about disabling comments to GitHub. Subscribe to updates here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/473#thread-subscription-status